# Not able to click link text in selenium web driver execuiton

Tags: eclipse, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to click hyperlink called "order create" in my application.I have used following code.When I execute this step in eclipse debug mode or selenium IDE, I am able to click particular link.However when I try to execute via Java mode in eclipse, my code is not able to click this link.Do we have any other option to click this link?(i.e wait and click something) [image]

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@href='link' and text()='Create Order'])).click();
```

Comment: plz share the source code or also have you tried Driver.findElement(By.linkText("order create")).click();

Comment: Driver.findElement(By.linkText("order create")).click(); I have tried.But I am facing same issue.Probelem here is my driver click the link before page loads.So could you please help em to give some wait comment.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors when trying to click the link? Also, can you share the HTML for the link element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit wait with expected condition [elementToBeClickable](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to wait for the element to be clickable

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@href='link' and text()='Create Order']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your drivers clicks before page load then there is a synchronization issue 
simplest way to avoid synchronization issue is use of universal wait i.e implicit wait which says driver instance to wait for a maximum of defined (time seconds) before sending any error.

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

in above code you are telling driver instance to wait a maximum of 20 seconds for the individual webelements in the current session.Note above wait is applicable for all webelements.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `Thread.sleep(2000);` before my test step.It has solved my issue.

Comment: @ Thread.sleep is not a good practice what will you do if same problem aries at different element